# Send signal to a Kubernetes Pod from GitLab CI job

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, kubectl

I am using a self-hosted Kubernetes cluster and I'm not using GitLab's Kubernetes integration. In my GitLab CI job, I'm changing the configuration of a Prometheus deployment in its associated ConfigMap, and I want to make Prometheus be aware of the new config by sending a `SIGHUP` signal to its process. Here is my job script to update the ConfigMap and send the signal:

```sh
for x in *; do kubectl get configmap prometheus-config -o json | jq --arg name "$(echo $x)" --arg value "$(cat $x)" '.data[$name]=$value' | kubectl apply -f -; done;
kubectl exec deployments/prometheus -- /bin/sh -c "/bin/pkill -HUP prometheus"
```

This approach works fine in my local terminal. After a manual change in ConfigMap and sending the signal by above command, I can see the effect after that in Prometheus.

The problem is that when I put these commands in my GitLab CI job script, it does seem to do nothing at all. The command successfully runs and my CI job is done, but nothing is refreshed in Prometheus.

I wonder if the way GitLab executes its jobs (the non-interactivity of the shell, etc.) causes this behavior, but I have no idea what I can do about it.

I also tried running a dummy `kubectl exec` in CI to see if it works at all:

```sh
kubectl exec deployments/prometheus -- /bin/sh -c "echo hi"
```

and it prints `hi` successfully. So, what's the problem with `kubectl` and GitLab CI when I'm sending a signal through it?

P.S. My approach to keep a Pod living and update it with new configuration instead of just restarting it may seem to be a bad practice, but if I restart the Pod, Prometheus takes 5~10 minutes to read the tsdb again, and I don't want to lose my monitoring system for just a configuration change. So, I'm sticking to sending that signal by now.

Comment: fyi the `exec` can run against the deployment to avoid the lookup. `kubectl -n prom exec deployment/prometheus -- ...`

Comment: I doubt that has anything to do with the problem due to the 'echo hi' working

Comment: @Matt Thanks about the deployment exec tip! I don't know if `kill` or its variations behave differently in such conditions :-? And I don't know what are these conditions exactly.

Comment: `pkill` and `kubectl` will normally pass the exit code on correctly so that the gitlab job fails. Test that by execing `exit 1` to see if it does fail. If yes then I'd look higher up that the configmap is actually updating properly.

Comment: The ConfigMap is updated successfully, I can verify it when that job is done. I'll test `exit 1` behavior, thanks. One thing I suspect is that if updating a ConfigMap requires some time to actually be applied, and when running it automatically, I lose the human work's delay. Don't you think this can be the case?

Comment: I would have said no as I thought configmap changes were "watched' for now [but this issue is still open](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74412). `cat` the yaml file the configmap maps to before the `pkill` to check.

Comment: Then you could `while ! grep -q 'someyamlkey: updatedvalue'; do sleep 1; done` if there is some specific data you can check for.

Comment: also https://github.com/jimmidyson/configmap-reload with the [http prometheus config reload option](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them up and I'll be back again. But your first link to Kubernetes issues is closed and somehow unrelated. Is it the one you wanted to mention?

Comment: Sorry.. too many kubernetes tabs : ) This is the configmap refresh issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30189

Comment: I think we've found the issue! `cat`ing the config file inside Prometheus right after applying changes of ConfigMap showed the change was not visibile! I added `sleep 15` before sending the signal and it worked! Thanks @Matt! I'll modify my question to show I'm `exec`ing right after updating ConfigMap, and it would be good if you post this in an answer so I can mark it as accepted. But I don't know this 15 seconds will be enough always, right?

Comment: Sorry Stack Overflow for this long comment thread, but according to [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/18082/files), "You can trigger an immediate refresh by updating one of the pod's annotations." I replaced that `sleep 15` with a change in annotations of my Prometheus Pod and its config file was synced successfully.

Comment: I can see that you find the solution can you post it as an answer it might probably help to other community members as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Config Maps do not [update immediately](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30189). There can be a delay of [up to 2 minutes](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/18082/files) (as of v1.18) for the changes to be reflected inside the Pod.

A common solution is to treat config maps as immutable data, so a new config map must be created which will need a new deployment template, and trigger a pod rollout. A timestamp or version number in the ConfigMap name usually works.

```
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: config-20200527-013643
```

Another solution is to include an annotation in the deployment template with a checksum of the config map data. When the checksum is updated, new pods will be launched with the updated ConfigMap. This is common in helm templates:

```
annotations:
  checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/config.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
```

In the specific case of prometheus slow start up, triggering a deployment pod rollout is technically a restart so the "outage" depends on whether or not the "readiness" probe for Prometheus meets your expectation of "online".

If you still need to use the SIGHUP, a shell [`test`](https://www.shellscript.sh/test.html) is able to compare file modification times with `-ot` and `-nt`. In a while loop, the job can wait for the configmap file to update:

```
kubectl exec deployments/prometheus -- /bin/sh -c "touch /tmp/cireload"
# apply config map changes
kubectl exec deployments/prometheus -- /bin/sh -c "while [ /tmp/cireload -ot /path/to/configmap.yaml ]; do sleep 5; echo "waiting for configmap $(date)"; done; /bin/pkill -HUP prometheus"
```

Comment: Solving this issue was full of tips from you! :D Thanks.

Comment: No worries. I do seem to have an issue with links though!